# Как очистить результат запроса mysqli для выполнения следующего запроса

Tags: php, mysqli

Небольшой код на PHP.
Суть : необходимо извлечь данные, выданные MySQL stored proc.
В этом конкретном примере stored вообще примитивна: select * from table limit num_lim

Задача состоит в том, чтобы выполнить два запроса один за другим, при этом второй запрос должен идти с флагом MYSQLI_USE_RESULT

Согласно документации для того чтобы запустить следующий запрос - я должен очистить результат предыдущего запроса - что я и сделал вызвав         mysqli_free_result($result);
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Вопрос: почему у меня не запускается второй запрос, а выдает ошибку
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
Согласно документации эта ошибка возникает когда не вызвана mysqli_free_result.

Подскажите пожалуйста - как мне выполнить два запроса ?

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "wt0615");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

/* Select запросы возвращают результирующий набор */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "call get_last_topics_post2(20)")) {
    printf("get_last_topics_post вернул %d строк.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    /* очищаем результирующий набор */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* Если нужно извлечь большой объем данных, используем MYSQLI_USE_RESULT */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM smf_members", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
    echo "smf_members",PHP_EOL;
    printf("Select вернул %d строк.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
    printf("Ошибка: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.free.php и ссылка на баг-репорт

Answer (score 1):

Ответ дан по информации Daniel Protopopov
Спасибо Daniel Protopopov !

Пользователь jack_action100@hotmail.example.com  отметил что вызов типа "call stored proc"
даже при простом возврате записей из одной таблице возвращает как минимум два результирующих набора.
В этом случае второй набор пустой и несет некоторую мета-информацию по вызову процедуры, особенно если случилась ошибка
( source:  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71044 )

В вышеприведенном коде после строки

```
 /* очищаем результирующий набор */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
```

надо добавить строку

```
mysqli_next_result($link);
```

И все работает!